# How to group ListBox items by date

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

Im trying to do simple task app. I have tasks with due date and I want to display it like this:

[image: this is what I want]

I know how to display data in listbox, but I dont know how to group them by DueDate and display that DueDates like headers (as it is in the image below).

This is my XML file with tasks (tasks.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Tasks>
  <Task>
    <Name>first task</Name>
    <DueDate>05/03/2013 00:00:00</DueDate>
    <Created>03/27/2013 01:24:08</Created>
  </Task>
  <Task>
    <Name>second task</Name>
    <DueDate>05/17/2013 00:00:00</DueDate>
    <Created>03/27/2013 01:24:19</Created>
  </Task>
  <Task>
    <Name>third task</Name>
    <DueDate>05/17/2013 00:00:00</DueDate>
    <Created>03/27/2013 01:24:38</Created>
  </Task>
</Tasks>
```

And this is my data model (MainViewModel.cs):

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<Task> Tasks { get; private set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.Tasks = new ObservableCollection<Task>();
    }

    public bool IsDataLoaded
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public void LoadData()
    {
        try
        {
            Tasks.Clear();

            var file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            XElement xElem;

            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream read = file.OpenFile("tasks.xml", FileMode.Open))
            {
                xElem = XElement.Load(read);
            }

            var tasks = from task in xElem.Elements("Task")
                        select task;

            foreach (XElement xElemItem in tasks)
            {
                string dueDate = "";
                DateTime convertedDate;

                if (DateTime.TryParse(xElemItem.Element("DueDate").Value.ToString(), out convertedDate))
                {
                    dueDate = convertedDate.ToShortDateString();
                }

                Tasks.Add(new Task
                {
                    Name = xElemItem.Element("Name").Value.ToString(),
                    DueDate = dueDate,
                    Created = xElemItem.Element("Created").Value.ToString()
                });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        this.IsDataLoaded = true;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (null != handler)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would use the LongListSelector Control in the [Silverlight Toolkit for Windows Phone](http://phone.codeplex.com/).

Here is a great [introduction](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part1-visual-structure-and-api) and also a [guide on databinding and grouping](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part2-data-binding-scenarios) which is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of one `ListBox` use two - the second one should be used in `ItemTemplate` of the first one.

With that approach your outer `ListBox` template ought to contain header (date of group) and inner `ListBox`. The inner one should have items.

With that approach you'll have to redesign your code behind to contain grouped data.

I would suggest `GroupOfTasks` class:

```
public class GroupOfTasks : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string ObservableCollection<Task> { get; set; }

    // you have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged by yourself.
}
```

And `LoadData` redesign:

```
public ObservableCollection<GroupOfTasks> Groups { get; private set; }

public void LoadData()
{
    try
    {
        Groups.Clear();

        (...)

        Groups = (from t in tasks
                  group t by t.DueDate into g
                  select new GroupOfTasks { Date = g.Key, Items = g.ToList() }).ToList();
    }
}
```

With `Groups` property bind your first `ListBox` to that property, and the inner one to `Items` property of current outer `ListBox` `Item`.

It's all just a hint, to show possible approach.